# React - How can I set "message from me"

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, axios

I have 2 states:

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ input: null });
const [outputData, setOutputData] = useState({ output: null });
```

formData is coming from my < input />. So, I am writing the input data by writing. outputData is coming from my GET api call.
I need to separate input data and output data. How can I tell the function if the message is from me?

```
function renderMessage(message) {
    //const here
    if (messageFromMe) {
      return <Me />;
    } else {
      return <You />;
    }
  }

  function Me(props) {
    return (
      <li className="Messages-message currentMember">
        <div className="Message-content">
          Hey its me
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }

  function You(props) {
    return (
      <li className="Messages-message">
        <div className="Message-content">
          Test
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Do you just want to render just one message at a time with the renderMessage function and that message would be whichever one has most recently changed?

Comment: @TaylorBurke Yes! Exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a good application for [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). The useEffect hook takes 2 arguments, a callback function (this could be your renderMessage) and an array of values. Whenever a value in the array changes, useEffect will call your function passed into the first argument. The hook itself would be inside of a higher-level component that would effectively parent your You and Me components when they are rendered by the callback of the hook.

Now we can do this:

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState(null);
const [outputData, setOutputData] = useState(null);
const [lastMessageSender, setLastMessageSender] = useState("");

let messageFromMe = (lastMessageSender === "me");

useEffect(()=>{renderMessage(message)}, [lastMessageSender]);
```

The last piece is this - whenever you call setFormData, also call setLastMessageSender and pass in the value "me" and whenever you call setOutputData, also call setLastMessageSender and pass in the value "you" - they could be other values eventually, such as the name of the user.

You may want to have convenience functions to help you code stay DRY...

```
const updateMessageFromOutput = payload => {
setOutputData(payload);
setLastMessageSender("you");
}

const updateMessageFromForm = payload => {
setFormData(payload);
setLastMessageSender("me");
}
```

Comment: It works, but I just want to render just one message at a time.

Comment: Ops - It returns for ALL messages. I just want to render just one message.

Comment: sorry @zicxor I didn't see your comment until today, do you still need assistance with this?